# Use certain values for X and Y axis in Calc

Tags: libreoffice

I'd like to create a chart with the wavelength as X-values and the corresponding voltage as Y-Values. I tried in vain for quite some time, could you please help me?

λ/nm
580
546
436

U/V
0,75
0,85
1,25

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put x and y values in two adjacent columns, select them then choose the menu item Insert->Chart.

In *Choose a chart type* select *XY (Scatter)*, next choose between the images on the right the type of lines (or points only) then click finish.

[image]